# Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/buckn/uploads/5th.jpg"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT

Tags: php, amazon-s3

this is the error i get
Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/infosecure.buck/uploads/5th.jpg"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/infosecure.buck/uploads/5th.jpg` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: AccessDeniedAccess Denied69DC61 (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): Access Denied - AccessDeniedAccess Denied69DC6155E0F5042AHg2jvV2iLEsOHnmsvxM2meASpYr9Z3I6zPxEPedneHixIaPZpfESW1/SCO0UwlVnTKBXwkatE0M=

```
<?php
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

require 'app/start.php';

if(isset($_FILES['file']))
{
   $file=$_FILES['file'];

  $name= $file['name'];

  $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];

  $extension = explode('.',$name);

  $extension=strtolower(end($extension));

  $key = md5(uniqid());

  $tmp_file_name= "{$key}.{$extension}";
  $tmp_file_path = "files/{$tmp_file_name}";
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$tmp_file_path);
  try{

     $s3->putObject([
     'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
     'Key' => "uploads/{$name}",
     'Body' => fopen($tmp_file_path,'rb'),
     'ACL' => 'public-read'

     ]); 

  unlink($tmp_file_path);}
  catch(S3Exception $e)
  {
      echo $e->getmessage();
  }




}
?>
```

this is my bucket policy

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::601825519382:user/admin-infosecure"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::infosecure.buck"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: what's the error? what are you trying to do?

Comment: i'm trying to upload files to s3 using php. and sorry about adding code i'm not able to add any code it says your post mostly contains code

Comment: there will be something more after 'PUT ..... Do you mind adding it to the question? adding some more context to the question like a code snippet will also go a long way.

Comment: yeah there is but the title limits me only to 150 chracters

Comment: now i've added it

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a permission issue.

If you are accessing via a local machine, make sure your IAM user has write access to the bucket.

If you are running this code on an EC2 instance, make sure the Instance Role has write access to this bucket.

Comment: have a look at my bucket policy

Comment: are you running this code from local or ec2? if ec2, are you accessing using using the same user: admin-infosecure? or using instance profile?

Comment: admin-infosecure is my iam user

Comment: Needed to add role to access the bucket

Answer (score 0):

For PutObject / GetObject the ARN needs to refer to the objects within the bucket, so instead of:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17"
, "Statement": [ {
    "Effect": "Allow"
  , "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::601825519382:user/admin-infosecure" }
  , "Action": "s3:*"
  , "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::infosecure.buck" 
  } ] 
}
```

You want

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17"
, "Statement": [ {
    "Effect": "Allow"
  , "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::601825519382:user/admin-infosecure" }
  , "Action": "s3:*"
  , "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:s3:::infosecure.buck"
    , "arn:aws:s3:::infosecure.buck/*" 
    ]
  } ] 
}
```